# Release lock on first table during stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, locking

I have what seems like a simple problem but can't find a solution.  I have a long-running stored procedure that will update a table at the beginning and end of the statement.  The problem is, the table is locked during the whole process.  Here's a simplified version:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_FullRefresh]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Settings SET SettingValue = 'true' WHERE SettingName = 'Running' 

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
END
```

The problem is, I'm unable to select that row from the `Settings` table while the whole procedure is running.  I even tried wrapping in transactions to see if that would help:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE Settings SET SettingValue = 'true' WHERE SettingName = 'Running' 
COMMIT;

BEGIN TRAN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
COMMIT
```

But that didn't work either.  Is there any way to release the lock on the `Settings` table while the procedure is doing its other stuff?

Comment: Also - even if you run your update in a transaction, it's **highly unlikely** the entire table will be locked; SQL Server uses **row-based** locks - so the row(s) you're updating might be locked - but not the whole table ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to release the lock on the Settings table while the procedure is doing its other stuff?

You are running the stored procedure in a transaction, otherwise the UPDATE statement would complete immediately, and be visible from other sessions.  When you add additional BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT pairs you're actually creating a "nested transaction"  The locks from the UPDATE will be held until the commit of the outer (real) transaction.

So just don't run the procedure in a transaction.

Some clients and data access/ORM frameworks start a transaction automatically, but most require you to explicitly start a transaction.

Comment: The row still won't be able to be read while there is an update lock on it though, even without the transaction.

Comment: Without a transaction any update lock will be released after the UPDATE statement, as each statement is running in its own transaction.

Comment: DOH!  How did I not realize that the outermost `BEGIN` and `END` were itself a transaction?  Here I am thinking it's just saying "here's the beginning and end of the stored procedure".  After removing the `BEGIN` and `END` it worked as expected.  Much appreciated!

Comment: True, but my understanding is that the OP is saying that have a long running tranasction, and that are "emulating" that by using a `WAITFOR` and a transaction. I could be wrong, of course. *Edit: Apparently it was that simple. :/*

Comment: @jmgardn2 so why have a `WAITFOR` in the SP at all? What purpose does it serve.

Comment: No.  The stored procedure `BEGIN` AND `END` do not create a transaction.  What I was saying is that you've got a transaction going _before_ the stored procedure is run.

Comment: Apologies, I jumped the gun with my test.  The WAITFOR is just emulating all my long running commands (to keep the question concise).  Your edit regarding the clients starting the transaction automatically actually helped guide me.  I am executing the procedure from EF (sorry for leaving that detail out).  Adding `TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction` to the call DID in fact get everything to work correctly.  Thanks!